# Youtube API Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to use youtube api to be able to search for videos through my site however, when ever I click on the search button nothing pop up.It does log what I have searched but no videos pop up. Help Please. I am currently running it on Cloud9. I did get the error that I am missing "}" but where it is tell me I am missing it, there is a bracket already there.

Here is the Java-script code :

```
     // JavaScript File
    $(function(){
    console.log(part1)
    var searchField = $('#query');
    var icon = $('#search-btn');
     console.log(data);
    //Focus Event Handler
    $(searchField).on('focus',function(){
        console.log(part2)
        $(this).animate({
            width:'100%'
        }, 400);
        $(icon).animate({
            right:'10px'
        }, 400);
        console.log(part3)
    });
    // Blur Event Handler

    $(searchField).on('blur',function(){
        console.log(part4)
      $("#searchfield").val('');{
          $(searchField).animate({ 
              width:'45%'

          },400, function(){});
          console.log(part5)
          $(searchField).animate({ 
              right:'360px'
          },400, function(){});
          console.log(part6)


        }


    });

    ('#search-form').submit(function(e){
      console.log(part7)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})

    function search(){
        //Clear Results
        console.log(part8)
        $('#results').html('');
        $('#buttons').html('');



     // Get Form Input
        q = $('#query').val();
    // Run GET Request on API
    $.get(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
            part:'snippet, id', 
            q: q,
            type:'video'
            key:" AIzaSyDjByBmG4PJdONQf2DZE_SBQHuhhoZGiHg "}
        function(data){
            console.log(part8)
            var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
            var previousPageToken = data.previousPageToken;
            /

    / Get OutPut
                console.log(part9);

            $.each(data.items, function(i, items){
               console.log(part10)
                // Get Output
                var ouput =getOutput(item);

                //Display Results
                $('#results').append(output);
                console.log(part11)


    });




    } 
    );
}

    // Build OutPut
     function getOutput(item){
          console.log(data);
         var videoID = item.id.videoID
         var title = item.snippet.title;
         var description = item.snippet.description;
         var thumb = item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url;
         var channelTitle = item.snippet.channelTitle;
         var videoDate = item.snippet.publishedAt;
         console.log(part12)
         // Built Output String
         var output ='<li>'+
         '<div class="list-left">'+
         '<img src="'+thumb+'">'+
         '</div>'+
         '<div class="list-right">'+
         '<h3>'+title+'</h3>'+
         '<small>By<span class="cTitle">'+channelTitle+'</span>on '+videoDate+'</small>'+
         '<p>'+description+'</p>'+
         '</div>'+
         '</li>'+
         'div class="clearfix"></div>'+
         '';

     return output;

 }
```

Comment: The console will tell you exactly where the problem is, line number and everything. For starters, you're missing a `$` on `('#search-form').submit(...` and that function seems to have an extra set of closings. Then, you're missing a comma in the ajax call, after `type: 'video'`, and it just goes on with small syntax errors, missing characters etc. that you seem to know about, but are too lazy to check for yourself.

Comment: Also, try pasting your code into http://jshint.com/ and following the recommendations.

Comment: adeneo is a bit rude, but right. If you are using Firefox as browser, you can use the Firebug extension to replace the original console, it will be a bit clearer for the debug part.